# Probability - conditional

Tags: probability

The probability that bulbs are detected faulty if they are defective is 0.95 and the probability that bulbs are declared fine if in fact they are fine is 0.97. If 0.05 of the bulbs are faulty, what is the probability that bulb that is declared faulty is fine?

Anyone can guide me for this question please?
I intepret F:the bulbs are faulty and D: The fault is detected. And get $\Pr(F)=0.05$ and $\Pr(D|F)=0.95$ and $\Pr(D^c|F^c)=0.97$. And try to find $\Pr(F^c|D)$,which is the answer. Using Bayes theorem, however I am not sure how to find the denominator of the theorem. Can help me?
Appreciate your help!

Comment: Are you familiar with Bayes' theorem?

Comment: @MarcusM yes however not sure what is the denominator in this case.can guide?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $D$ represent defective bulbs and $F$ denote that the bulb is detected as faulty. You now have $\Pr(F|D)=0.95$ and $\Pr(F^c|D^c)=0.97$, as well as $\Pr(D)=0.05$.

Comment: I intepret F:the bulbs are faulty and D: The fault is detected. And get $\Pr(F)=0.05$ and $\Pr(D|F)=0.95$ and $\Pr(D^c|F^c)=0.97$. And try to find $\Pr(F^c|D)$,which is the answer. Using Bayes theorem, however I am not sure how to find the denominator of the theorem. Can help me?